# Make Alexa Skill play audio

Tags: python, python-3.x, alexa-skills-kit

I've tried very hard to figure out how to make my Alexa skill to play audio but I cannot find a solution. I emailed the amazon developer support and they sent me the following code. I would love it if someone could explain to me the logic behind this code. Also, how would I make this code into a fully functional Alexa skill? Thank you.

```
import logging
import typing

from ask_sdk_core.skill_builder import SkillBuilder
from ask_sdk_core.dispatch_components import (
   AbstractRequestHandler, AbstractRequestInterceptor, AbstractExceptionHandler)
import ask_sdk_core.utils as ask_utils

from ask_sdk_core.utils import is_intent_name, is_request_type
from ask_sdk_core.api_client import DefaultApiClient
from ask_sdk_core.skill_builder import SkillBuilder, CustomSkillBuilder

from ask_sdk_core.dispatch_components import AbstractRequestInterceptor
from ask_sdk_core.dispatch_components import AbstractResponseInterceptor
from ask_sdk_model.services.service_exception import ServiceException

if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
   from ask_sdk_core.handler_input import HandlerInput
   from ask_sdk_model import Response

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

WELCOME_MESSAGE = "This is Alexa regular speech, followed by the sound effect named Bear Groan Roar <audio src='soundbank://soundlibrary/animals/amzn_sfx_bear_groan_roar_01'/>"
WHAT_DO_YOU_WANT = "What do you want to ask?"

class LaunchRequestHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
   """Handler for Skill Launch."""

   def can_handle(self, handler_input):
       # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool

       return is_request_type("LaunchRequest")(handler_input)

   def handle(self, handler_input):
       # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response

       return handler_input.response_builder.speak(WELCOME_MESSAGE).ask(WHAT_DO_YOU_WANT).response

sb = CustomSkillBuilder(api_client=DefaultApiClient())

sb.add_request_handler(LaunchRequestHandler())
```

Comment: Are you trying to play a short audio clip when the user launches the skill or asks a question? Or are you trying to play a streaming music station or audio file longer than 90 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are trying to play a streaming music station, if this is the case, this will be implemented using AudioPlayer interface, please find more information on the link below:
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html

There is an AudioPlayer sample skill which actually streams from a radio station already to which you can refer. That can be found here: https://github.com/alexa-samples/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player , also in python https://github.com/alexa-samples/skill-sample-python-audio-player . You will need to change the url stream and add your own.

Please take into account that the URL you provide in the audioItem.stream.url property must meet these requirements:
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html#audio-stream-requirements